# Joomla is detecting wrong screen height

Tags: html, css, joomla, screen

I'm using Joomla 2.5, I notice that Joomla is detecting wrong screen height 1123.640 * 261

the width is right but height is totally wrong, I don't want to use min-height in css to fix that issue.

I tried to go through template.js or core.js to fix that issue

[image]

Comment: You need to elaborate this error. Joomla does not detect height. What sort of template are you using. This seems to be a template issue, but it is really impossible to say from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue after rearranging the layout positions